# Python - Getting url a browser was redirected to

Tags: python, redirect, browser, urllib2

I am trying to authenticate an application with the API.
Here's How:

1. I am opening a URL using `webbrowser.open`.
2. The user authenticates the application, and is redirected to another URL, which is
   `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`with arguments encoded with this URL.
    A sample redirect url is:
   `.../login_success#access_token=xyz&expires=00000`

My Current code:

```
auth_url = 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog'
def authenticate():
    scope = "write_access,private_info,read_inbox"
    url = make_url(auth_url,client_id=132,
                   scope=scope,response_type='code',
                   redirect_uri='https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success')
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

How can I get the redirect URL (the URL the user is taken to) after the user authenticates themselves???

Comment: Aren't you supposed to redirect to a URL that points to *your* host and use the request that appears on your server to find out if the user was logged in successfully? I gather you're inside a client application, so you might want to fire up a minimal HTTP server and redirect to `localhost:yourport`.

Comment: @svckr Yes, but It should also be possible to see what happened from the url. How can I open my `localhost` to the page??

Comment: `webbrowser` can't be used for that, it's really only meant for opening browsers but not to interact with them.

Comment: Implement OAuth yourself (using one of the fine Python implementations that exist).

Comment: @robertklep What do you mean, pls elaborate...

Answer (score 3):

Try to fire up your own little HTTP server for just one request, let the API redirect to it and wait for the redirected request to appear. This is not a complete example, just the basic concept:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
auth_url = 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog'

# replace with your own http handlers
def wait_for_request(server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer,
                     handler_class=BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    return httpd.handle_request()

def authenticate():
    scope = "write_access,private_info,read_inbox"
    url = make_url(auth_url,client_id=132,
                   scope=scope,response_type='code',
                   redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/login_success')
    webbrowser.open(url)
    wait_for_request()
```

You probably need to use HTTPS though. In the long run, you might be better off with an existing OAuth implementation.

Comment: Application Login Failure:

An error occurred while login into an application.
Error Details:

error description: application not configured for implicit grants

Comment: Oh, my bad. The `redirect_url` has to be under a domain registered with the stack-app. So no luck with `localhost`. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realized that I was making a silly mistake.
If you are redirecting and you need the url from the browser, you will have to make sure that you have the endpoint available that the other application can point back to.

```
  scope = "write_access,private_info,read_inbox"
  url = make_url(auth_url,client_id=132,
                   scope=scope,response_type='code',  redirect_uri='https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success')
   redirect(url)
```

you can redirect the user in the same window they are in, and then
the other application you redirected them to, will redirect them
back to your application using the redirect_uri you specified.

Answer (score -1):

After the user authenticates with stack exchange, the SE page will redirect back to your page ("redirect_uri" below). Your code currently redirects to https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success ; instead, you should redirect to a page you control.

1. Open a new window at https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog, with these query string parameters

   - client_id
   - scope
   - redirect_uri
   - state - optional
2. The user approves your app
3. The user is redirected to redirect_uri, with these parameters in the hash

   - access_token
   - expires - optional, only if scope doesn't contain no_expiry

source: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

Comment: redirect_uri should be a page on your server

Comment: Then there is no way to do oauth. At the very least, you could create a server running on localhost to redirect to

Comment: if you just want to experiment, http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html. Many environments like Rails and GAE also come with simple servers for local testing