# how to open web browser with python and return url of the rediredcted page

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, oauth

I want to  use facebook api for which I will be needing oauth token, so when the program starts the python program will open the the authentication url by webbrowser.open() method after this the user will will give permission and then facebook will generate access token and redirect to a different link. I need to grab this redirected link and retrieve the access token. How do I grab this redirected url.

Comment: I don't think you can do this simply by using the webbrowser module. But you can test OAuth on localhost. Bit of googling will get you quite far.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no simple way to do this (see [Python - Getting url a browser was redirected to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492917/python-getting-url-a-browser-was-redirected-to))
If you have a WebServer set the redirect page to your server and the get Tokens from there.

Otherwise use the python oauth module.

If you have a fb-app (with id and token) you can do it locally, althrough its not a very good/safe way..